# SassError after Update Angular to v15

Tags: angular, npm, angular-material

> I'm updating my Angular from v14 to v15. I already executed the commands 'ng update @angular/core@15 @angular/cli@15' and 'ng update @angular/material@15'.

When trying to start the application I get this Error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/shared/components/warning-dialog/warning-dialog.component.scss?ngResource
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Only 0 arguments allowed, but 1 was passed.
  ┌──> src/styles/theme.scss
177│ @include mat.core($regular-font);
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ invocation
  ╵
  ┌──> node_modules/@angular/material/core/_core.scss
8 │ @mixin core() {
  │        ━━━━━━ declaration
  ╵
  src/styles/theme.scss 177:1                                                 core()
  src/styles/theme.scss 177:1                                                 @import
  src/app/shared/components/warning-dialog/warning-dialog.component.scss 1:9  root stylesheet
 @ ./src/app/shared/components/warning-dialog/warning-dialog.component.ts 11:0-78 40:17-37
 @ ./src/app/shared/shared.module.ts 73:0-94 112:4-26
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 37:0-54 74:12-32
 @ ./src/main.ts 3:0-45 9:41-50
```

This is my theme.scss

```
> 
> @use '~@angular/material' as mat;
> 
> $mat-theme-ignore-duplication-warnings: true;
> 
> $color-xxx-accent1-shade2: #ffea99; $color-xxx-accent5-shade2:
> #8ba68a; $color-xxx-accent6-shade1: #B21014; $color-xxx-basic3-shade2: #c2c2c2;
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> /*  Color Theme */ $xxx-normal-palette: (   50 :  #FFFFFF, 
> // color-xxx-basic5   100 : #E9EBF1,  // color-xxx-highlight-shade3  
> 200 : #D2DAE3,  // color-xxx-highlight-shade2   300 : #BDC6D6,  //
> color-xxx-highlight-shade1   400 : #92A2BD,  // color-xxx-highlight  
> 500 : #6c7c97,  // color-xxx-form-button-main-dark   600 : #ACBCD7, 
> // color-xxx-form-button-main-light   700 : #7C89A1,  //
> color-xxx-form-button-shade1   800 : #526482,  //
> color-xxx-form-button-shade2   900 : #000000,  // color-xxx-form-text 
> A100 : #444444, // color-xxx-basic4   A200 : #666666, //
> color-xxx-basic3   A400 : #EEEFEA, // color-xxx-basic2   A700 :
> #AAA38E, // color-xxx-basic1   contrast: (
>       50 :  #000000,
>       100 : #000000,
>       200 : #000000,
>       300 : #000000,
>       400 : #000000,
>       500 : #000000,
>       600 : #000000,
>       700 : #000000,
>       800 : #000000,
>       900 : #000000,
>       A100 : #000000,
>       A200 : #000000,
>       A400 : #000000,
>       A700 : #000000,   ) );
> 
> $xxx-normal-palette-accent: (   50 :  #FFF5CC,  //
> color-xxx-accent1-shade3   100 : #FFEA99,  // color-xxx-accent1-shade2
> 200 : #FDDF66,  // color-xxx-accent1-shade1   300 : #FECB00,  //
> color-xxx-accent1   400 : #FF9100,  // color-xxx-form-border-accent  
> 500 : #ffad1f,  // color-xxx-signal3   600 : #E5E3DD,  //
> color-xxx-basic1-shade3   700 : #D4D1C6,  // color-xxx-basic1-shade2  
> 800 : #C3BEB0,  // color-xxx-basic1-shade1   900 : #F6F6F6,  //
> color-xxx-table-shade   A100 : #E0E0E0, // color-xxx-basic3-shade3  
> A200 : #C2C2C2, // color-xxx-basic3-shade2   A400 : #A3A3A3, //
> color-xxx-basic3-shade1   A700 : #666666, // color-xxx-basic3  
> contrast: (
>       50 :  #000000,
>       100 : #000000,
>       200 : #000000,
>       300 : #000000,
>       400 : #000000,
>       500 : #000000,
>       600 : #000000,
>       700 : #000000,
>       800 : #000000,
>       900 : #000000,
>       A100 : #000000,
>       A200 : #000000,
>       A400 : #000000,
>       A700 : #000000,   ) );
> 
> $xxx-normal-palette-warn: (   50 :  #ECEECC,  //
> color-xxx-accent3-shade3   100 : #DADE99,  // color-xxx-accent3-shade2
> 200 : #C7CE66,  // color-xxx-accent3-shade1   300 : #A2AD00,  //
> color-xxx-accent3   400 : #3db014,  // color-xxx-signal2   500 :
> #d20000,  // color-xxx-signal1   600 : #DADADA,  // color-xxx-accent2-shade3   700 : #B4B4B4,  // color-xxx-accent2-shade2
> 800 : #8F8F8F,  // color-xxx-accent2-shade1   900 : #D26666,  //
> color-xxx-accent2   A100 : #EFEFEF, // color-xxx-form-button   A200 :
> #D9D9D9, // color-xxx-form-field   A400 : #999999, // color-xxx-form-border   A700 : #000000, // color-xxx-form-text  
> contrast: (
>       50 :  #000000,
>       100 : #000000,
>       200 : #000000,
>       300 : #000000,
>       400 : #000000,
>       500 : #000000,
>       600 : #000000,
>       700 : #000000,
>       800 : #000000,
>       900 : #000000,
>       A100 : #000000,
>       A200 : #000000,
>       A400 : #000000,
>       A700 : #000000,   ) );
> 
> $xxx-primary: mat.define-palette($xxx-normal-palette);
> $xxx-accent: mat.define-palette($xxx-normal-palette-accent);
> $xxx-warn: mat.define-palette($xxx-normal-palette-warn);
> 
> $xxx-theme: mat.define-light-theme($xxx-primary,
> $xxx-accent, $xxx-warn);
> 
> @include mat.all-component-themes($xxx-theme);
> 
> /* xxx Typography */ @font-face {   font-family: "xxxGroup_Cond_Bold";
> src: url('assets/fonts/xxxGroup_Cond_Bold.ttf') format("truetype");  
> font-style: normal;   font-weight: normal; }
> 
> @font-face {   font-family: "xxxGroup_Cond_Regular";   src:
> url('assets/fonts/xxxGroup_Cond_Regular.ttf') format("truetype");  
> font-style: normal;   font-weight: bold; }
> 
> $xxx-bold-font: mat.define-legacy-typography-config(   $font-family:  
> 'Group_Cond_Bold',   $headline:         
> mat.define-typography-level(18px, 32px, 700),   $title:            
> mat.define-typography-level(20px, 32px, 700) );
> 
> $xxx-regular-font: mat.define-legacy-typography-config(  
> $font-family:       'Group_Cond_Regular',   $display-4:        
> mat.define-typography-level(112px, 112px, 300),   $display-3:        
> mat.define-typography-level(56px, 56px, 400),   $display-2:        
> mat.define-typography-level(45px, 48px, 400),   $display-1:        
> mat.define-typography-level(34px, 40px, 400),   $subheading-2:     
> mat.define-typography-level(16px, 28px, 400),   $subheading-1:     
> mat.define-typography-level(16px, 24px, 400),   $body-2:           
> mat.define-typography-level(14px, 24px, 500),   $body-1:           
> mat.define-typography-level(14px, 20px, 400),   $caption:          
> mat.define-typography-level(12px, 20px, 400),   $button:           
> mat.define-typography-level(14px, 14px, 500),   $input:            
> mat.define-typography-level(inherit, 1.125, 400) );
> 
> /* Font sizes */ $font-size-large-18:  18px; $font-size-large-24: 
> 24px; $font-size-normal-12: 12px; $font-size-normal-16: 16px;
> $font-size-small-10:  10px; $font-size-small-8:   8px;
> 
> /* Font weights */ $font-weight-bold:    700; $font-weight-normal: 
> 400; $font-weight-thin:    300;
> 
> @include mat.typography-hierarchy($xxx-regular-font);
> 
> @include mat.all-component-typographies($xxx-regular-font);
> 
> /* Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once! */ @include
> mat.core($xxx-regular-font);
> 
> 
> /* Button colours */ .mat-button, .mat-button-toggle,
> .mat-raised-button {   &.mat-raised-button:hover {
>     background-color: mat.get-color-from-palette($xxx-accent, 700);    }   &.mat-primary:not(:hover) {
>     background-color: mat.get-color-from-palette($xxx-primary, 400);
>     color: mat.get-color-from-palette($xxx-primary, 50);   }   &.mat-primary:hover {
>     background-color: mat.get-color-from-palette($xxx-primary, 500);
>     color: mat.get-color-from-palette($xxx-primary, 50);   }   &.mat-primary[disabled] {
>     background-color: mat.get-color-from-palette($bxxx-primary, 300);
>     color: mat.get-color-from-palette($xxx-primary, 100);   } }
```

I already deleted node_modules and package-lock and installed it again. But it didn't help.

I also deleted material and installed v14 again. With that there was no error. Then I updated it to v15, and there was the Error again.

So is there a change in material that I have to adapt? But what, and how?

I would be so thankful for any help! I'm searching so long for solution, but wasn't successful yet.

Comment: Please share the code of `src/styles/theme.scss` including the list of imports.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `define-typography-config` has changed in V15 with the migration to MDC for `@angular/material`.

The previous one is now under `define-legacy-typography-config`.

So you have 2 choices :

- You use `define-legacy-typography-config`
- You move to the new `define-typography-config` which is defined like following :

```
@function define-legacy-typography-config(
  $font-family:   'Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif',
  $display-4:     define-typography-level(112px, 112px, 300, $letter-spacing: -0.05em),
  $display-3:     define-typography-level(56px, 56px, 400, $letter-spacing: -0.02em),
  $display-2:     define-typography-level(45px, 48px, 400, $letter-spacing: -0.005em),
  $display-1:     define-typography-level(34px, 40px, 400),
  $headline:      define-typography-level(24px, 32px, 400),
  $title:         define-typography-level(20px, 32px, 500),
  $subheading-2:  define-typography-level(16px, 28px, 400),
  $subheading-1:  define-typography-level(15px, 24px, 400),
  $body-2:        define-typography-level(14px, 24px, 500),
  $body-1:        define-typography-level(14px, 20px, 400),
  $caption:       define-typography-level(12px, 20px, 400),
  $button:        define-typography-level(14px, 14px, 500),
  // Line-height must be unit-less fraction of the font-size.
  $input:         define-typography-level(inherit, 1.125, 400)
```

---

Edit:

You should pass the typography to the theme directly :

```
$theme: (
    color: (
        primary: $primary,
        accent: $accent,
        warn: $warn,
    ),
    typography: $xxx-regular-font,
    density: 0,
);

mat.define-light-theme($theme),
```

Comment: You mean I change 
$-regular-font: mat.define-typography-config() to 
$-regular-font: mat.define-legacy-typography-config()
in my theme.scss?

Comment: Yes that's what you can do !

Comment: Now I have another Error. How can I add a new quote here?

Comment: Go edit your question ;)

Comment: Ah, could be improved :-D
Edited it.

Comment: You can see my edit !

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Can you give a before/after example, please?

Comment: remove your call to `mat.core()` and update the call to `define-light-theme` to include the typography !

Comment: It's SassError: Undefined mixin now.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

Change your `mat.define-typography-config` to `mat.define-legacy-typography-config`

```
$regular-font: mat.define-legacy-typography-config(
  $font-family:       'Group_Cond_Bold',
  $headline:          mat.define-typography-level(18px, 32px, 700),
  $title:             mat.define-typography-level(20px, 32px, 700)
);
```

And the `@include mat.core($regular-font)` to `@include mat.typography--hierarchy($regular-font)`

```
@include mat.typography-hierarchy($regular-font);
```

Thanks for the hints!